# Why can't I find any go package which follows the standard src/pkg/bin structure?

Tags: go, directory-structure

I'm a beginner in golang, and I was reading the article [How to write Go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) on the go website. It explains how the typical Go structure contains three folders in the root of the project:

```
bin/
    contains compiled code
pkg/
    contains package objects
src/
    contains the Go source files
```

So to learn from other projects I checked out some popular go projects in github, but to my surprise I don't see this src/pkg/bin structure in any of those projects.

What am I missing here? Does anybody know a (preferably simple) project in golang which follows this structure? I think I could learn a lot from reading other people's code.

Comment: That's the structure of GOPATH, not packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you reference in your question is not how projects are structured but rather how the local workspace is configured.

https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces

Typically, you'll set up one workspace in your local machine, for example you would set up your workspace root to be:

`$HOME/go`

You then point your GOPATH environment variable to `$HOME/go` to let Go know that's your workspace location.

Inside your workspace you then create the `src`, `bin` and `pkg` folders that the documentation describes.

Inside `src` is where you checkout (or create your own) project folders.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now. Do you mean to say that I will have ALL my projects in separate repositories in the `src/` folder? So whenever I open my editor (Gogland) I always open the same project, in which I then open the src folder of my choice?

Comment: And the advantage is that you can always use all packages in all your projects right? Does it also mean that packages imported with `go get package` exist in the same `src/` folder next to your own projects and packages?